# How to Retrieve TRAITS of NFT from OpenSea with JavaScript?

Tags: node.js, api, blockchain, nft

I have a website and i am wonder how can i get the Traits of NFT from OpenSea. Can anybody help me and i really need a suggestions. Thank you for your help.
Below is the traits i fetch on OpenSea docs

```
 "traits": [
        {
          "trait_type": "original shirt",
          "value": "collared shirt white",
          "display_type": null,
          "max_value": null,
          "trait_count": 0,
          "order": null
        },
        {
          "trait_type": "original background",
          "value": "red",
          "display_type": null,
          "max_value": null,
          "trait_count": 0,
          "order": null
        },
        {
          "trait_type": "original type",
          "value": "plain mfer",
          "display_type": null,
          "max_value": null,
          "trait_count": 0,
          "order": null
        },
        {
          "trait_type": "original eyes",
          "value": "eye mask",
          "display_type": null,
          "max_value": null,
          "trait_count": 0,
          "order": null
        },
        {
          "trait_type": "mouth",
          "value": "smile",
          "display_type": null,
          "max_value": null,
          "trait_count": 0,
          "order": null
        },
        {
          "trait_type": "original headphones",
          "value": "white headphones",
          "display_type": null,
          "max_value": null,
          "trait_count": 0,
          "order": null
        },
        {
          "trait_type": "original smoke",
          "value": "cig black",
          "display_type": null,
          "max_value": null,
          "trait_count": 0,
          "order": null
        },
        {
          "trait_type": "original 4:20 watch",
          "value": "oyster silver",
          "display_type": null,
          "max_value": null,
          "trait_count": 0,
          "order": null
        }
      ],
```

Check out API on here: https://docs.opensea.io/reference/retrieving-assets-rinkeby

Answer (score 0):

The OpenSea API allows you to retrieve the traits of an NFT by making a GET request to the /nft/{id}/traits endpoint. The {id} in the endpoint is the ID of the NFT for which you want to retrieve the traits.

Comment: So, how to get it but with JavaScript code. That how i concerned, i am stuck how to code to get it

Comment: There are many ways to make JavaScript API requests. Some popular libraries include:

-Fetch
-Axios
-Request
-Superagent

Comment: You can read more about every single one of them

Comment: WOW thank you for your suggestion, if you can get it with JavaScript, i hope you can post the code here